# how do i search for documents within a sharepoint site based of guid or uuid using web services?

Tags: java, web-services, sharepoint, caml

One can search for files in sharepoint if the list or document store is known. But, how can a document can be searched for if only the site or subsite is known but the list is not known.

We are trying to achieve this using the Sharepoint Web services for both Sharepoint 2007 and Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using. Have you looked at the SPQuery class?

Comment: we are try to achieve this via Webservices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search is only possible within a particular Document Library. Sharepoint cannot across multiple document libraries or sub-sites.